# R Cumulative calculation based on prior values in the same column

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, cumsum

This is what my dataframe looks like. `V3` is my desired Column. `V3` **is not available to me.**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('

Level  V1  V2  
  0    10  2     
  1     0  3     
  1     0  2    
  1     0  2 ')
```

I am trying to calculate V3 based on prior values of V3. The V3 formula is:

```
New Value of V3 =((Prior Value of V3+ Prior Value of V3*V2)*Level)+V1
1st Row V3 = (NA+NA*3)*1 + 10 = 10
2nd Row V3 = (10+10*3)*1 + 0 =40
3rd Row V3 = (40+40*2)*1 + 0 =120
4th Row V3  = (120+120*2)*1 + 0 = 360
```

The output should look like this.

```
Level  V1  V2  V3
  0    10  2   10  
  1     0  3   40  
  1     0  2   120 
  1     0  2   360
```

I was trying:

```
dt[,V3:= (cumsum(V3+V3*V2)*Level)+V1]
```

Comment: Special features of the problem might go a long way here. For example, if you know that V1 is always nonzero to start and zero thereafter, as in this example, you have `V1[1] * cumprod((Level*(1 + V2))[-1])`

Comment: I'm guessing you want to get V3 only using Level, V1, V2, but if so it is not clear enough (as seen by the answers below, which use V3 to build V3).

Comment: @Frank My intention is to use V1, V2 and V3 generated by V1,V2 from the prior row to build the New V3.

Comment: Ok, but that entails only using V3[1], the first element, right? If I'm reading the other answers correctly, they are using other elements of the vector as well. Anyway, I am probably misunderstanding.

Comment: @Frank No, you are right. I am using V3[1] to get the ball rolling. I dont have the V3 column available for me to generate the new V3. I am trying to use `dt[,V3:= V1[1] * cumprod((Level*(1 + V2))[-1])]` but it shows an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reworked your efforts in the comments to get the desired result:

```
 dt[,V3:=cumprod( c(V1[1] ,(Level*(1 + V2))[-1]) ) ]
 dt

   Level V1 V2  V3
1:     0 10  2  10
2:     1  0  3  40
3:     1  0  2 120
4:     1  0  2 360
```

I didn't actually get an error (only a warning) with dt[,V3:= V1[1] * cumprod((Level*(1 + V2))[-1])]. Using the [-1] shortened the cumprod with no extension, and resulted in recycling.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The `cumprod` idea originally came from @Frank

Comment: I find myself wondering if this approach could be used to build simulations of difference equations that involved multiplication of noisy sequences.

Comment: Here is related problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495918/calculating-reinvestment-of-dividends-with-a-cumulative-approach. I have tried to use cumprod in this to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Within `data.table`

```
dt[,{ lag.V3=c(0, V3[-.N]) ; V3 = (lag.V3 + lag.V3 * V2 )* Level + V1 }]
```

Output

```
[1]  10  40 120 360
```

Comment: Fyi, data.table introduced a shift operator, so you can do something like `shift(V3, type = "lead", fill = 0)`. Also, no reason not to simplify `(lag.V3 + lag.V3 * V2)` to `(1+V2)*lag.V3`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank Hi Frank, Would you mind posting your 'shift' solution as an answer?

Comment: @gibbz00 Sorry, it's not really a complete answer. I was just pointing out how `c(0, V3[-.N])` can alternately be written.

Comment: @MFR the thing is I can only use V1, V2 and Level to generate V3. I dont have V3 to generate new V3. I mentioned at the beginning of the post that V3 is my desired column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in `dplyr`

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(V4=lag(V3) + lag(V3)*V2 + V1,
         V4=ifelse(is.na(V4), 0, V4))

  Level V1 V2  V3  V4
1     0 10  2  10   0
2     1  0  3  40  40
3     1  0  2 120 120
4     1  0  2 360 360
```

Comment: In case you want to remove the `ifelse` section, you can set the NA to any arbitrary number using the `default` argument from the `lag` function.

Comment: @JasonWang I edited the post. I can only use V1, V2 and Level to generate V3. I dont have V3 to generate new V3. I mentioned at the beginning of the post that V3 is my desired column.