# Calculating reinvestment of dividends with a cumulative approach

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my data.table looks like. The A:E columns are just to draw comparison to excel. Column `NewShares` is my desired column. I **DO NOT** have that column in my data.

```
            A           B        C         D         E          F
 dt<-fread('                 
  InitialShares     Level     Price    Amount   CashPerShare NewShares
         1573.333       0      9.5339   13973.71    0          1573.333
           0            1      10.2595    0       .06689       1584.73
           0            1      10.1575    0       .06689       1596.33
           0            1      9.6855    0       .06689       1608.58')
```

I am trying to calculate `NewShares` with the assumption that new shares are added to `InitialShares` by reinvesting dividends(`NewShares*CashPershare`) at 90% of the price(`Price*.9`). In excel land the formula will be `=F2+((F2*E3*B3)/(C3*0.9))` as of the second row. The first row is just equal to `InitialShares`.

In R land, I am trying(which is not quite right):

```
dt[,NewShares:= cumsum(InitialShares[1]*Level * CashPerShare/(Price*.9)+InitialShares[1])]
```

Please pay attention to the Decimal points of `NewShares` once you generate the field in order to validate your approach.

Comment: @eddi I am sorry. I put in the wrong price in column C. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand your formula, you'll realize that this works:

```
dt[, NewShares := cumprod(1+Level*CashPerShare/Price/0.9)*InitialShares[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried the `cumprod` approach too. For some reason, could not get it to work.